# Why is std::vector erase very slow in release only when I step over with the debugger?

Tags: c++, vector, std, stdvector

Ok let's start over

I'm trying to erase an element from a std::vector and for some reason it is very slow in release mode only when I step over.

Here is the complete source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

class data
{
public:
    int i;
};

void Test(int n)
{
    std::vector<data> v;
    data d;

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(d);
    }

    ULONGLONG nTick = GetTickCount64();
    v.erase(v.begin()+1);
    std::cout << n << " " << GetTickCount64() - nTick << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Test(10000);
    Test(100000);
    Test(1000000);

    return 0;
}
```

When I step over the line

```
    v.erase(v.begin()+1);
```

it take respectively in release

```
10000 -> 2 seconds
100000 -> 18 seconds
1000000 -> 182 seconds
```

but is pretty much instant in debug for all of them?

Comment: Please present a complete, compileable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What Ben said. And in the meantime, is the size of the vector greater than `nPos` when this freeze happens?

Comment: I wish I could but I would have to give the hole thing as it doesn't happen when I try in a small test application.

Comment: @Potato The size of the vector is 600000 and nPos is 2

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the `data` class?

Comment: @Pat: where is the data class?You are showing a point class!

Comment: I think we need a FAQ on guidelines for changing identifier names to protect the guilty.  In summary: Make a copy of your entire project directory, globally rename the identifier, then compile *after* the rename, and show actual errors reproducible with the exact code being shown in the question.

Comment: Is it just really slow because its copying (600000 - 2) * 3 * sizeof(double) bytes of data? A list/forward_list might be better for this use case

Comment: @Aravind I thought there were a quick answer to my problem so I just put a dummy class name. Obviously not! Sorry for that.

Comment: @RichardBruce I thought about using list but I need very quick access and very small footprint. Each list elements are created individually which consume a lot more memory. Also the case that doesn't freezes is pretty much instant.

Comment: @Pat , that's cool, but it's sorta misleading, so you could get answers like "Change name in vector definition".

Comment: @RichardBruce A personal computer can move ~15 megabytes pretty darn fast.

Comment: @Pat This isn't what we're looking for. See http://sscce.org . It's likely you overflowed a buffer before getting to this line, and overwrote the internal member of the `vector` which implements `begin`.

Comment: @Pat: with the code provided, I don't think there's an error.probably there is an error before all this, which by this tiny snippet is incomprehensible.So maybe you should post your source code somewhere, or it's hard to help you!

Comment: If it happens in your code but not in a small example, then the cause must lie in the difference between the two. This being the case, we can't possibly help if you just post an example that you say, "this doesn't work," but it actually does. If we're going to help you, then you'll need to share something that we can use to reproduce the problem. Either find a small example that _does_ reproduce the error, or share your complete code with the error. That said, you could try running it through `valgrind` to see if you've done something weird to the memory...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I put the full source code which have the problem I'm talking

Comment: @Pat: It's instant for me in Release mode.  Visual Studio 2012 with a new console application, all the default settings.

Comment: So it must be a Visual Studio 2010 problem

Comment: Don't "put the full source code". You _must_ present a reproducing testcase.